# Install bum on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, services

I am trying to install bum (BootUp manager) on Ubuntu 17.04.

I have tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get install bum` however I get `Unable to locate package bum` error.

Is there anyway to install bum on Ubuntu 17.04?
If not what other gui system/service managers are available?

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu zesty, `bum` is not available to you

Comment: @JohnJoe and why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to open http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bum in Chrome. Then the browser asks to choose opening with **xdg-open** or not. See the screenshot below:

[image: xdg-open modal window]